# WCF Configuration without a config file

Tags: wcf, configuration, configuration-files

Does anyone know of a good example of how to expose a WCF service programatically without the use of a configuration file? I know the service object model is much richer now with WCF, so I know it's possible. I just have not seen an example of how to do so. Conversely, I would like to see how consuming without a configuration file is done as well.

Before anyone asks, I have a very specific need to do this without configuration files. I would normally not recommend such a practice, but as I said, there is a very specific need in this case.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend such a practice (exposing the service programatically without configuration)?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Consuming a web service without a config file is very simple, as I've discovered. You simply need to create a binding object and address object and pass them either to the constructor of the client proxy or to a generic ChannelFactory instance. You can look at the default app.config to see what settings to use, then create a static helper method somewhere that instantiates your proxy:

```
internal static MyServiceSoapClient CreateWebServiceInstance() {
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    // I think most (or all) of these are defaults--I just copied them from app.config:
    binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 );
    binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 );
    binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 );
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 10 );
    binding.AllowCookies = false;
    binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
    binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
    binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
    binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
    return new MyServiceSoapClient( binding, new EndpointAddress( "http://www.mysite.com/MyService.asmx" ) );
}
```

Comment: I personally like this approach for examples when you are going to be using the file in a different matter, for example, if you've encrypted your app.config (or equivalent config file) and don't need to use the built in WCF capabilities of it reading in a connection

Comment: For https usage, add 
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

Comment: This worked quite well for me.  The only differences for me is that I also set the ReaderQuotas and Security information.  I made use of ciscoheat's advice and set the Security.Transport.Mode to Transport if using https (for me this is not known at compile time).

Comment: I just verified that all of the properties being set are equal to the defaults in WCF 4, fwiw. (But note that `Security.Mode` defaults to `None`.)

Answer (score 19):

If you are interested in eliminating the usage of the System.ServiceModel section in the web.config for IIS hosting, I have posted an example of how to do that here (http://bejabbers2.blogspot.com/2010/02/wcf-zero-config-in-net-35-part-ii.html).  I show how to customize a ServiceHost to create both metadata and wshttpbinding endpoints. I do it in a general purpose way that doesn't require additional coding. For those who aren't immediately upgrading to .NET 4.0 this can be pretty convenient.

Comment: John, I'm sure that's a great blog post, but since there's an accepted answer from 17 months ago, is there really any purpose to your answer?

Comment: Since this is my first Stack Overflow answer that may not be the way things are usually done.  Being familiar with the Lowy and Bustamante books, which are great references, I think my answer goes well beyond the samples they offer.  I primarily use Stack Overflow when googling so I read posts that are older frequently.  Having more up to date answers only helps from my perspective.  I googled this post before writing my code to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: ok, but when you read the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq, linked on every page), you'll find this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. There was already a lot of "A" for this "Q", and 17 months ago, so IMHO, this is questionable.

Comment: you may want to see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40696/what-to-do-about-late-answers-if-anything, where I've used your post as an example.

Comment: As a frequent SO user, I find it quite desirable to read new posts on old topics. It helps me do my job better, which increases the value of this site (as myself and others will visit it more). Rather than being a stickler with rules, why not allow people to discuss so better answers might be discovered? Isn't that the point?

Comment: Seems John Saunders was put in his place with the response to his own question (none of which he has accepted as the answer I might add). I personally have no problem with late replies to questions, and am usually delighted to see a new response to a question I asked, months if not years later. Ironically, I earned my own Necromancer badge with my accepted answer to this very question. :)

Comment: I had the same issue, and the accepted answer did not help me, but this did, hurrah for late answers!

Had it not been for late answers, I would have had to create a duplicate question of this.

Answer (score 15):

Here, this is complete and working code. I think it will help you a lot. I was searching and never finds a complete code that's why I tried to put complete and working code. Good luck.

```
public class ValidatorClass
{
    WSHttpBinding BindingConfig;
    EndpointIdentity DNSIdentity;
    Uri URI;
    ContractDescription ConfDescription;

    public ValidatorClass()
    {  
        // In constructor initializing configuration elements by code
        BindingConfig = ValidatorClass.ConfigBinding();
        DNSIdentity = ValidatorClass.ConfigEndPoint();
        URI = ValidatorClass.ConfigURI();
        ConfDescription = ValidatorClass.ConfigContractDescription();
    }


    public void MainOperation()
    {
         var Address = new EndpointAddress(URI, DNSIdentity);
         var Client = new EvalServiceClient(BindingConfig, Address);
         Client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
         Client.Endpoint.Contract = ConfDescription;
         Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "companyUserName";
         Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "companyPassword";
         Client.Open();

         string CatchData = Client.CallServiceMethod();

         Client.Close();
    }



    public static WSHttpBinding ConfigBinding()
    {
        // ----- Programmatic definition of the SomeService Binding -----
        var wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();

        wsHttpBinding.Name = "BindingName";
        wsHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        wsHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        wsHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        wsHttpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        wsHttpBinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        wsHttpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
        wsHttpBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        wsHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
        wsHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
        wsHttpBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
        wsHttpBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        wsHttpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        wsHttpBinding.AllowCookies = false;

        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384;
        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;
        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;
        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;

        wsHttpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
        wsHttpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        wsHttpBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = false;

        wsHttpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.Realm = "";

        wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;
        // ----------- End Programmatic definition of the SomeServiceServiceBinding --------------

        return wsHttpBinding;

    }

    public static Uri ConfigURI()
    {
        // ----- Programmatic definition of the Service URI configuration -----
        Uri URI = new Uri("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWcfServiceLibrary/EvalService/");

        return URI;
    }

    public static EndpointIdentity ConfigEndPoint()
    {
        // ----- Programmatic definition of the Service EndPointIdentitiy configuration -----
        EndpointIdentity DNSIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("tempCert");

        return DNSIdentity;
    }


    public static ContractDescription ConfigContractDescription()
    {
        // ----- Programmatic definition of the Service ContractDescription Binding -----
        ContractDescription Contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IEvalService), typeof(EvalServiceClient));

        return Contract;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice example! You demonstrate nearly every aspect of manual configuration. Nicely done!

Comment: I don't understand how EvalServiceClient fits into this code. It's referenced, but not defined. Why is the server creating a client?

Answer (score 5):

It is not easy on the server [side](http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2006/12/04/overriding-the-default-configuration-file.aspx)..

For client side, you can use [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

All WCF configuration can be done programatically. So it's possible to create both servers and clients without a config file.

I recommend the book "Programming WCF Services" by Juval Lowy, which contains many examples of programmatic configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I found the blog post at the link below around this topic very interesting.

One idea I like is that of being able to just pass in a binding or behavior or address XML section from the configuration to the appropriate WCF object and let it handle the assigning of the properties - currently you cannot do this.

Like others on the web I am having issues around needing my WCF implementation to use a different configuration file than that of my hosting application (which is a .NET 2.0 Windows service).

http://salvoz.com/blog/2007/12/09/programmatically-setting-wcf-configuration/

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to do on both the client and the server side. Juval Lowy's book has excellent examples.

As to your comment about the configuration files, I would say that the configuration files are a poor man's second to doing it in code. Configuration files are great when you control every client that will connect to your server and make sure they're updated, and that users can't find them and change anything. I find the WCF configuration file model to be limiting, mildly difficult to design, and a maintenance nightmare. All in all, I think it was a very poor decision by MS to make the configuration files the default way of doing things.

EDIT: One of the things you can't do with the configuration file is to create services with non-default constructors. This leads to static/global variables and singletons and other types of non-sense in WCF.