# Would like to call WCF service wihout adding service refernce

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am confused that how can i call WCF without adding reference of that. I need to test WCF is running or not only do not need other use of that, that's why i am searching to call it without adding reference of that. I came to know that using svcutil.exe we can do that and searched for it but could not find any solution, so anyone can help me to do this stuff?

Thanks
Arun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like you are looking for is the WCFTestClient that comes with visual studio. This is typically located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE for 64bit users) and it is called WcfTestClient.exe

For a pure code solution i suggest looking at this SO answer: [WCF Configuration without a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54579/701062)

Comment: @gray , not found, generally i would like to test this in code behind of asp.net page

Comment: im sorry it should be Visual Studio 10.0 for VS 2010

Comment: update answer to include link for a code solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/54579/701062