# Class library error, calling Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, class-library

I have a class library, which calls into a Webservice. When i try and instantiate a new instance of the client, I am being thrown the following error is VS:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'SanctionsCheckingService.ISanctionsCheckingService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

My app.config file contains the following, which looks correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISanctionsCheckingService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:56200/SanctionsCheckingService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISanctionsCheckingService"
            contract="SanctionsCheckingService.ISanctionsCheckingService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ISanctionsCheckingService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Can anyone point to why this is happening?

Comment: is that the app.config of the dll or the executing program?

Comment: See this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036542/cannot-call-wcf-webservice-from-dll

Comment: @GrahamHull, this is the app.config of the class lib

Comment: @GrahamHull, followed your suggestion, and that solved it. Kind of feel slightly embarrassed now :-) Anyways, move your comment into an answer, i'll award you the kudos