# Is it good practice to place Service Reference when consuming WCF in library(.dll) project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have to consume a WCF Service. I have multiple layers in my project. I have one output project and other are library projects. All are dll projects except one output project. I would like to know the best place to place my service references. This is one serious architecture related concern that I want to understand.

The best thing that I found is that App.config or Web.config are placed in output projects. I should add service references in output project only because it is it generates bindings and other endpoint details in config file only. I will be required to copy paste all the things in output project only if place it in dll projects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the WCF configurations into the main web.config or app.config project.  Whatever the executing program is. Referenced here: [Cannot call WCF WebService from DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8036542/3047)

Or don't use configurations at all, do it programmatically like here: [WCF Configuration without a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54579/3047)