# Is there a way to reference a web service from a .net 2.0 app without using a config file?

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx, asp.net-2.0

In a .Net 2.0 COM application I am referencing a web service.

In COM components I want to use the Constructor String to store my end point address and deploy my component without any config file.

I see that when I create my web service reference that the endpoint is put all over the place in the various files that get created.

Ideally I would like to be able to programmatically configure my endpoint and not rely on the config at all.  Is there any way to do this?

I am familiar with programmatically setting endpoints and bindings with WCF services, but as this is a .net 2.0 app, I am forced to go with an old style asmx / wsdl reference.

Comment: Have you tried the above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160176/programmatically-create-endpoints-in-net-wcf-service ?

Comment: I looked at that already.  The System.ServiceModel namespace did not exist in .net 2.0.

Comment: Have you tried then webclient ?

Comment: No, I'm looking into it now.

Comment: For my work i use it a lot. I avoid to add as webrefence services. But unfortunately i use it for wcf so i don't have any example to post.

Comment: It seems that it is too radical of a change for my codebase.  I am using the generated service references throughout.  Switching to webclient would require a large refactor.  I'll keep it in mind as a last resort.

Comment: Indeed is a big refactor, but you control them better. Good luck with your challenge.