# How to invoke methods on external server / webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to invoke methods from http://www.ibanbic.be/IBANBIC.asmx

I have read a lot of forums and tutorials, but all the information is about setting up a webservice in ASP.net or using ajax / javascript. I just need to call the function: calculateIBAN1.

A tutorial step by step would be awesome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: a simple search on google gave me tons of examples... like this one: http://ctrlf5.net/?p=66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A tutorial step by step would be awesome.

Right click on the `References` menu in your project in the solution explorer and choose `Add Service Reference...`. In the address type `http://www.ibanbic.be/IBANBIC.asmx` and click `Go` and then `OK`. This will generate a strongly typed client proxy that will allow you to invoke the service:

```
using (var client = new ServiceReference1.BANBICSoapClient("IBANBICSoap"))
{
    string result = client.calculateIBAN1("iso country", "some account");
}
```

Notice that this will also add a `<system.serviceModel>` to your web.config file where you could manage the WCF client endpoints.

Alternatively you could use the `svcutil.exe` to generate a client proxy for the service as shown in [`this article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: The system.serviceModel is added to webconfig, so the first part worked. I'm using MVC4 so when i click the button my controller executes the http post of that page. The code that you've pasted should that be in that httppost? Thanks for answering btw

Comment: Strange but I get this InnerException.Message: 'Unable to connect to the remote server'

Comment: @BadaBoom, that's probably because the machine you are running your application in doesn't have access to the server on which the web service is hosted. Or maybe there's a firewall or proxy in between preventing the access.

Comment: I added code to consume Web Services without a config file - find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579/wcf-configuration-without-a-config-file

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET:

First you have to add a web service:

[image]

And then you have to instantiate the webservice and call the method.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for answering, but add web reference is not in my options, add service reference is (Is this the same?). I'm using a MVC4 project maybe that's why there isn't web references?

Comment: Well, here is best explained about web reference and service reference  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference) but to simplify, service reference is the new way to do it. So, add the service reference and instantiate the method.

Answer (score 0):

based on their site
    http://www.ibanbic.be/IBANBIC.asmx?op=calculateIBAN1

You can make a simple Ajax call like this:

```
var ISOCountry = 'IT';
var account = 'IT60 X054 2811 1010 0000 0123 456';
var url = "http://www.ibanbic.be/IBANBIC.asmx?op=calculateIBAN1"
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            timeout: 4000,
            data: {'ISOcountry':ISOCountry, 'account' : account},
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError,
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function() {
            }
        });
}
function onSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // do something
}
function onError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // do something
}
```