# Get SOAP request in C#

Tags: c#, soap

In my console application I added a service reference to http://www.ibanbic.be/IBANBIC.asmx .
The operations in it I need to use.

Now, this is my little piece of code, and from what I saw in tutorials, this should be enough to connect to it and get a value. But the only value I get is "String is Empty".

```
using (BANBICSoapClient WebService = new BANBICSoapClient())
{
string bban = "*****";
   try
   {
      string resultIban = WebService.BBANtoIBAN(bban);
      if (resultIban != string.Empty)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(resultIban);
      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("String is empty.");
      }
   }
   catch(Exception msg)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(msg);
   }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Can anyone give me some more information about what is wrong?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16062767/969613) may help.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that one!

Comment: I checked it, but still; my result is an empty string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you passing a valid BBAN or just the string of asterixes?  Do you have a sample of valid data?

Calling the web service with data I just mocked up, e.g. (12345, *****) looks to return an empty string, so that's what it might return in the event of invalid data.

Comment: No, I'm passing a valid BBAN in my code.. I pass this string: 428608677145

Comment: Try 510-0075470-61 as the BBAN and this should return a correct value.

Comment: Passing in 428608677145 manually doesn't look to return anything.