# WCF - Where to put client config

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf service, which i would like to invoke from an html page, using a activex.
The html have the activex on it, and the activex is the client to the wcf service.
where should the client config be?

ty.

Comment: Have you create Rest service for that?

Comment: Consider using [code only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292810/21567) configuration.

Comment: @Christian.K, what is code only?