# How to add an WCF Service reference in my SSIS script task

Tags: c#, wcf, ssis

I have script task which manipulates some data and send them as an requestObject to a WCF service, I have added the service reference as we do in visual studio and I did not have any compile time error , but when i am running the SSIS package I am getting the below error :-

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MYWrapperService.IMyWrapperService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.

how to solve this, please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the way out and it is working, thanks to  [WCF Configuration without a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579/wcf-configuration-without-a-config-file) I just replaced my service name and end point address and added the below  line to create the instance and used this object :-

MyWrapperService.MyWrapperServiceClient objMyWrapperService = CreateWebServiceInstance();

and more important it works in SSIS script task :)

Thanks  [WCF Configuration without a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579/wcf-configuration-without-a-config-file)